# How to consume a web service using username?

Tags: 8

I have set up a very simple web service in another server, using plain PHP, which receives data as GET, does a database search, and retrieves a JSON string. From the server where Drupal is installed, I could get the data using CURL.

Now I need to do the same in Drupal, using username as parameter. How can I achieve this?

All I can find relates to creating web services in Drupal rather than consuming them.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after a lot of research and guessing I think I've solved it, this is my solution in case anyone needs it

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class MyModuleController extends ControllerBase {
  protected $httpClient;

public function __construct(Client $http_client) {
  $this->httpClient = $http_client;
}

public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
  return new static(
    $container->get('http_client')
  );
}

public function content() {
  $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
  $name = $user->get('name')->value;
  $myurl = 'http://(remote url)?doc='.$name;

  $request = $this->httpClient->request('GET',$myurl);

  if ($request->getStatusCode() == 200) {
     $datos = $request->getBody()->getContents();
     return ['#markup' => $datos,];
  }
}
}
?>
```

This only shows the answer as a string, now I'll have to parse it, etc, and add some security and validation.
Opinions are welcome.